# Android studio 3.4 not showing preview device for older version

Tags: android-studio

I have recently updated my Android studio to 3.4,but after that i am unable to see the preview of older devices lower than 5.0. Thanks in advance

[image: This is the screenshot]

Comment: Hi devinder please check this screen shot that might help you http://prntscr.com/nobkfn

Comment: What exactly are you asking about? 5.0 has two meanings - size and version

Comment: Small configurations are under Generic phones and tablets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Go with this steps shown in Image go to -:> Generic Phones and Tablets**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

All the smaller screen devices below 5.0 are moved to **Generic Phones and Tablets** option.